# How to configure Capistrano to deploy to same directory?

Tags: capistrano

I understand that Capistrano (v2.15.5) deploys to a different directory and symlinks them in deploy:create_symlink however we have a proprietary module on our web server that breaks on every deploy as its licensed to a specific directory. I understand the advantages of the symlink and being able to rollback etc. but we need to deploy to the same directory. I can't find any documentation which supports this, is it possible without editing the source?

Comment: did you get it to work eventually?

Comment: No, overriding the release_name did deploy to the same directory but we encountered corruption in the deployed folder i.e. not matching the  deployed branch, presumably as a result of the rsync not working correctly.

Comment: but you're not sure if it's not because of the override after all? Unfortunately, I can't help with the branch issue because I only ever used it to deploy jars I downloaded from nexus.

Answer (score 0):

Provided I understood you correctly, this should help:

`set :deploy_to, "<proprietary path>"`

This will put the releases dir and the current symlink into `<proprietary path>`.

For more control over all relevant directories, have a look at deploy.rb from the 2.x branch here:

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/legacy-v2/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb

In particular lines 50-66. You can overwrite all the _cset statements with set just like in the example above.

Comment: Thanks but you didn't understand me. I don't want the subdirectory within the releases directory to change on every deployment. By default it deploys into a timestamped directory and symlinks 'current' to it. In other words I need  current to always point to the same underlying directory as the proprietary module detects this directory as changing after every deployment e.g. from /srv/www/releases/20140317093109/ to /srv/www/releases/20140318143008/

Comment: in that case, line 48 is of particular interest. Try setting a constant value for `:release_name` instead of the timestamp and set :deploy_timestamped to false

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to do it without editing source. Looking at the source, what about overriding :release_name? Cant I just add 'set :release_name, "static"' in the relevant capfile?

Comment: if by Capfile you mean the actual ruby script containing the tasks then: yes, you override it in your own script. No need to modify the Capistrano source